# DataView.getInt16 returning values less than -32768

Tags: javascript, binary, webkit, v8

I've been parsing binary font files for years without issues and am just now getting strange result from code like this.

```
const value = dataView.getInt16(offset, false);
```

Which either returns correctly or is off by exactly -65536. These off results are only happening about 0.25% of the time and I've not been able to identify anything that is triggering this.

So if the correct value is 2 sometimes I'm seeing -65534.

The lowest 16 bit number should be -32768 so these values should be impossible from my understanding. Is there something that can cause this, or a correct way to transform them?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, needs a repro to investigate.