# Javascript V8 Torque Engine Loading Binary Data Improperly

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, chromium, v8

We load font files using opentype.js and have found a bug either in our code, the V8 engine, or Chromium that returns the result of `DataView.getInt16()` as `65536` lower or higher than it should be. This occurs very rarely (~0.25%), but that's still hundreds of times a day for our users. As a result, we can only reproduce it on a couple of our computers and not consistently. Some browser tabs will always work and others will always give the incorrect value.

I am not a binary operations expert, but know the basics.

Here's an example: Say we expect `513`.

In binary we would expect:
`00000000000000000000001000000001` (513)

If the result is `+65536`, we can explain this with the 17th bit being flipped:
`00000000000000010000001000000001` (66049 - 65536 = 513)

If the result is `-65536`, we can explain this with the full set of preceding 16 bits being flipped:
`11111111111111110000001000000001` (-65023 + 65536 = 513)

It seems that sometimes, somehow, either the 17th bit gets flipped to a `1` or the entire set of bits filled in the front to satisfy the 16-bit to 32-bit conversion are flipped to `1` including the two's complement.

We've been debugging for a few days and are looking for help in how we should tackle this problem. We'd like confirm whether or not this problem is our code or something recently introduced into chromium or v8.

Comment: I stumbled upon this article that explains the least significant bit determines if the item is a heap pointer or an Smi. I don't know how that plays into what we're seeing, but might be worth noting:

https://medium.com/fhinkel/v8-internals-how-small-is-a-small-integer-e0badc18b6da

Comment: A little bit confused here, you talk about `getInt16` and the show some binary representation of a 32bit value.

Comment: Sounds like a bug (and like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76706445/dataview-getint16-returning-values-less-than-32768), needs a repro to investigate.

Comment: In V8 code, `getInt16` pulls 2 8-bit (1-byte) data pieces out of a buffer and then pulls each into a variable of type `int32`. Therefore, the data must be stored in 32 bits. I could be wrong, but that is the only way I can explain what we're seeing.

Comment: @JoshRoss Of course the bytes must get put into either a smi or float at some point, that's what JavaScript will be working with. The question is just where/how/why does the extra bit get added inadvertently? Or maybe it's an uninitialised variable/memory issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess: this could be [crbug.com/1466088](https://crbug.com/1466088). The fix is already making its way through the release channels.

If that guess is right, then:

- This bug occurs only on arm64 hardware, e.g. Macs with M1/M2 chips, and most Android devices. It never happens on Intel/AMD CPUs.
- This bug occurs only when the new "Maglev" optimizing compiler is enabled. Starting a fresh Chrome instance with `--js-flags="--maglev"` makes it much more likely to happen, starting Chrome with `--js-flags="--no-maglev"` prevents it from ever happening.
- This bug occurs only when the most-significant bits of the two bytes of the value you're loading differ. That means it wouldn't happen for the 513 in your example; it would happen for values like `0b1xxxxxxx0xxxxxxx` or `0b0xxxxxxx1xxxxxxx` (where `x` means "0 or 1, doesn't matter").

Can you confirm any of these observations?

Comment: Thanks for following up and figuring out how to reproduce this. Starting chrome on our macs with maglev enabled (`open -a Google\ Chrome --args --js-flags="--maglev"`) makes reproduction very likely to occur. I've been able to see it on my system with that flag flipped. Any ideas as to why some people who would not have known to enable maglev have it on and others don't? Is it randomly set at install? We heard reports that reinstalling the browser resolved the issue for people.

Comment: To clarify, the example I chose (513) was completely random and not based on actual numbers. I was simply trying to illustrate what could possibly be occurring.

Comment: @jnr Maglev is currently going through a gradual rollout, to flush out any last bugs (like this one!) before turning it on for everyone soon. Just restarting Chrome is enough to roll the dice whether it's enabled; reinstalling is not required (and won't have any permanent effects with respect to this).